# Install program from source to chroot env

Tags: installation, deb, install-from-source, bazaar, chroot

I have an program source (Remmina) and want to install it to chroot environment. Remmina uses `cmake` system.

I can install it to chroot using:

```
sudo make install DESTDIR=mychroot
```

but this is not nice method because I need to make sure the chrooted system meets all requirements (dependencies). I think the best idea is to create deb package and then install it under chroot. But how?

Oh I forgot to tell that I am using bazaar (with git plugin) and saw there is buildpackage plugin to build debs. Maybe this way would be better?

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

If you're not short of a bit of space, you could use `debootstrap` to install a minimal complete OS in your chroot. This then makes `apt` available in your chroot.

To start with:

```
sudo apt-get install debootstrap
```

To setup a new chroot:

```
sudo debootstrap oneiric /path/to/chroot
sudo chroot /path/to/chroot /bin/bash
```

Voila, you're in a new minimal Ubuntu installation. `apt-get` will work from here. So now you could even install `gcc`/`make` et al, and do your entire `make install` in the chroot, which should pretty much guarantee the end result will work properly (all the libs will be present and so forth).

There's a few other steps you should do like setting up /proc in the fstab in the chroot, see the `debootstrap` manpage (under EXAMPLES).

Comment: I have my own debootstrap installation but I don't want to install all the needed sources there. I wan't update program source and install into the chroot. I have apt under chroot but I don't have package (only source files).